# Javescript code is showing in banner ads #ADMOB

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads, google-ad-manager

Its not very often also not reproducible but reported multiple times now.
Sometimes on banner ad view, javascript code started showing.

Also. I'm using `PortraitAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize` with max height of 50 dp for ad size on this placement.

Couldn't find anything related to this issue, can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Does it happens on every campaign or only this one ? It looks like it is a creative problem (script being interpreted as text)...

Comment: this is not campaign or placement specific, happens randomly.... @rabsom

Comment: oes your app prevent execution of external scripts ? Looks like this javascript is interpreted as text (encoded version ?)

Comment: We're not restricting JS in app, mostly (99%) it work just fine on same app, same device.